# Can WCF Service Host call its service?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, windows-services

This is my project:

IWCFService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SetValue(string value);

    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveToDatabase();
}
```

WCFService.cs

```
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public void SetValue(string value);
    {
        //Code insert value
    }

    public bool SaveToDatabase);
    {
        //Code save values to database
    }
}
```

WindowsServiceHost.cs

```
public partial class WindowsServiceHost : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost _host;

    public WindowsServiceHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof (WCFService.WCFService));
        _host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _host.Close();
    }
}
```

frmClient.cs

```
public partial class frmClient : Form
{
    private WCFServiceClient _client = new WCFServiceClient();

    public frmClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.SetValue(39);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.SetValue(50);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.SaveToDatabase();
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
}
```

Where can I put shared memory (to set value from many clients)? (in WCF Service or Windows Service)

Can I call SaveToDatabase() from Windows Service? (calling automatically after 5 seconds)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Web service method call should be considered as complete operation, so if you need to store passed values, you should call `SaveToDatabase` somewhere inside `WCFService.SetValue()` and there's no need to expose `SaveDatabase` as web service method.